# Is it possible to set a regular expression so that NSTextView can be used with code completion?

Tags: regex, nstextview, code-completion

I have implemented code completion for Objective-C with `NSTextView` using clang. I use the `- textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:` method of `NSTextViewDelegate` to do this. The problem is that when the user types something like this:

```
struct a {
  int some_member;
} *c;
c->
```

and hits <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> to do the autocompletion, NSTextView treats the `>` character as if it were part of the word to be completed. The result would look like this:

[image: screenshot]

How can I make NSTextView only treat `@?[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*` as completable words?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `-[NSTextView rangeForUserCompletion]` and return the range of the word to be completed.